# Java IF Statement necessary?

Tags: java, logic

I have:

```
String str = "Hello, how, are, you";
```

I want to create a helper method that removes the commas from any string. **Which of the following is more accurate?**

```
private static String removeComma(String str){
    if(str.contains(",")){
        str = str.replaceAll(",","");
    }
    return str;
}
```

**OR**

```
private static String removeComma(String str){
    str = str.replaceAll(",","");
    return str;    
}
```

Seems like I don't need the IF statement but there might be a case where I do. 
If there is a better way let me know.

Comment: Well, have you considered what could happen if you leave out the `if` statement?

Comment: Don't use [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) unless you are using regular expressions. Use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are functionally equivalent but the former is more verbose and will probably be slower because it runs an extra operation.

Also note that you don't need `replaceAll` (which accepts a regular expression): `replace` will do.

So I would go for:

```
private static String removeComma(String str){
    return str.replace(",", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The IF statement is unnecessary, unless you're handling "large" strings (we're talking megabytes or more).

If you're using the IF statement, your code will first search for the first occurance of a comma, and then execute the replacement. This could be costly if the comma is near the end of the string and your string is large, since it will have to be traversed twice.

Without the IF statement, commas will be replaced if they exist. If the answer is negative, your string will be untouched.

Bottom rule: use the version without the IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but the second one is cleaner since the IF statement of the first alternative is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of what is the probability to have strings with comma in your universe of strings.

If you have a high probability, call the method replaceAll without checking first.
BUT If you are not using extremely huge strings, I guess you will see no difference in perfomance at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution with time complexity O(n), space complexity O(n):

```
public static String removeComma(String str){
    int length = str.length();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c != ',') {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Suggestions: Use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`, lazy-initialize it (such that you can just return `str` if it didn't contain any `,`), and pass `length` to its constructor to prevent resizing.